# Abbreviating Serial Number from XML file in XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, formatting

This is probably fairly trivial, but I'm new to XSLT and have been stumped while trying to find a way to shorten the length of a serial number that must be displayed in a table. I have an XML file that contains timestamped data about numerous electric meter readings. My goal has been to take the meter data from the XML file and transform it into a table that is easily viewable in Internet Explorer via stylesheet. I have the parsing and table set up correctly, so i'm now working on a few small things to clean up the table.

The meters are each named with Electronic Serial Numbers(ESN) within the XML file. The ESN is a 22 digit unique identifier in this format **3.54.765.2.233245.4.64352456** the only part of the ESN that is necessary to display in the table is the last 8 digits (in this example case **64352456**).

I've tried various things with the **format-number()** command, but it seems to have problems with this serial number because it isn't a real number. Within my stylesheet I am retrieving and storing the ESN as the variable "ESN" and displaying it in the table later on as the full ESN, any ideas on how to shorten the MeterID to its last 8 digits is greatly appreciated! Here's my stylesheet, I don't think I can post the XML because of company privacy stuff. Thanks!

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:local="#local-functions"
    xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"

    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" 
                      xmlns:itron="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Itron.Ami.AmiServiceTest.Hosting"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d2p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/data"
    xmlns:d3p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/common"
    xmlns:d5p1="http://www.itron.com/ami/2008/10/events"
    xmlns:d7p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="/">
<!--        Print Title     -->
    <div>AMI DATA</div>
<!--        Create Table and column headings        -->
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color:#C0C0C0; font-weight:bold">

                <td>Meter ID</td>
                <td>Vh(a)</td>
                <td>Max V(a)</td>
                <td>Min V(a)</td>
                <td>Vh(c)</td>
                <td>Max V(c)</td>
                <td>Min V(c)</td>
                <td>Timestamp</td>
            </tr>
<!--        Loop through each DataSubscriberItem (each a seperate meter)   create  variables to store TimeDataEnd, PulseMultiplier, and Meter Identifier           -->
    <xsl:for-each select="XMLRoot/itron:DataSubscriberItem">
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="EndTime" select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel/d2p1:TimeDataEnd"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="PulsMult"   select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadPr ofileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel/d2p1:PulseMultiplier"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="ESN" select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:Identifier"/>
        </div>
<!--        Variable to keep count of entries within each DataSubscriberItem.
    It's later used to assign timestamps based on TimeDataEnd       -->         
            <xsl:variable name="NumPnts" select="count(itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[1]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue)"/>
            <xsl:for-each   select="itron:DataArrivedInput/d2p1:ReadDataCollection/d2p1:ReadData/d2p1:LoadProfileChannels/d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[1]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue">
                <xsl:variable name="INum" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="EndTime2" select="../../d2p1:TimeDataEnd"/>
<!--        Start filling in table with true Voltage and Vh values      -->                 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ESN"/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vha" select="d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>                    
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vha*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vmaxa" select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[2]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vmaxa*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vmina" select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[3]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vmina*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vhc" select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[4]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vhc*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vmaxc" select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[5]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vmaxc*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:variable name="Vminc" select="../../../d2p1:LoadProfileChannel[6]/d2p1:IntervalValues/d2p1:IntervalValue[$INum]/d2p1:ChannelValue"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number($Vminc*$PulsMult,"0.###")'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:variable name="SDTS" select="concat(substring($EndTime2, 1,10), ' ', substring($EndTime2, 12,5))"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="local:timeCalc($SDTS, $INum, $NumPnts)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>


</xsl:template>
<!--        VBScript to create seperate timestamps from INum variable and  TimeDataEnd      -->
<msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="local">
        <![CDATA[
    Function timeCalc(ET, PT, TP) 
        SDT1 = CDate(ET)
        SDT = DateAdd("n", -(TP-PT)*5, SDT1)
        TTR =  PadOut(Month(SDT)) & "/" & PadOut(Day(SDT)) & "/" & Year(SDT)& " " & PadOut(Hour(SDT)-4) & ":" & PadOut(Minute(SDT))
        timeCalc =   TTR
    End Function

    Function PadOut(n)
        If n < 10 Then
            PadOut = "0" & n
        Else
            PadOut = n
        End If

    End Function
]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried various things with the **format-number()** command, but it seems to have problems with this serial number because it isn't a
>   real number.

No, it is not a number - it's a string. To display the last 8 characters of a string, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($ESN, string-length($ESN) - 7)"/>
```